# modify datepick plugin to popup calendar when an icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

Im using a jQuery calander plugin called [datepick](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) on my site. I connect the datepicker to my input field like this:

```
 $('.dobOnly').datepick();
```

Here's a working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedD0D/xzzCf/6/)

By default the calendar pops up when the user clicks on the input. Instead, Id like for it to only pop up if the user clicks an icon next to the input.

Its propbly important to mention that there are several of these inputs on the page Im working on. As such it seems likely that a solution would have to include modifying `datepick()` to take the id of the related text field as an argument so that the pop up affects the intended input.

**What would be the best way to edit waht I have to accomplish this?**

Comment: you can try datepicker http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation you need to wrap the image in a hidden div.  Then in the options for `datepick` specify the `showOnFocus` and `showTrigger` properties.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="gd2" id="gd2"/>
<div style="display:none">
    <img id="calImg" src='https://pnrbuilder.com/_images/cal.png' alt=""/>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(function() {
    $('#gd2').datepick({showOnFocus: false, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
 });
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/xzzCf/7/

There is an example of this on the `invocation` tab of the [documentation](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)